# SQL Server 2008 R2 Missing Parameter

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, ado.net

My `System.Data.SqlClient` reports that I forgot to pass a parameter.

Well I have been scratching my head over this.

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 with Asp.Net MVC2 in VS2008.

Here is the screen.

[image]

What did I miss ?

**EDIT**

Here is the Stored Procedure Header

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClientMst_AUTO](@Params VARCHAR(50),@result   xml output)
as
BEGIN
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual SQL statement you're using? Also: when you define a `SqlParameter` of type `SqlDbType.VarChar` - you should **always** define a length - otherwise you might end up with a string of 1 character length!

Comment: You mean Stored Procedure or Command Text ?

Comment: If it's a stored procedure - then the stored proc header (to see what the parameters look like) - otherwise the full SQL statement.

Comment: You want to call a procedure called "GetInvoiceHdr_AUTO", the exception states that you call "ClientMst_AUTO". Unless these procedures have the same prarameter list, it's hardly likely to work.

Comment: Sorry i pasted the wrong proc. anyway both have same header. I just updated it with right stored proc.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code!

Comment: The behavior is un believable. That's why i posted the screen. thanks anyway for the advice. ill keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks good at first glance - the only point I'm seeing that *might* explain the behavior is this: you've defined your parameter `@result` as being `ParameterDirection.InputOutput` - but you're not supplying any value for that parameter on the *input* side...

Try to add this line before you add `parm2` to the `cmd.Parameters` collection:

```
parm2.Value = string.Empty;
```

Does that change anything?

**OR:** just define the parameter as `ParameterDirection.Output` (instead of `InputOutput`) - does that solve the problem?

Comment: SPOT ON !! That was exactly the problem. thanks a lot marc. Now its working fine after initializing the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to pass a value into your `@result` parameter, set `parm2.Direction` to `ParameterDirection.Output`.

Comment: thanks but in all my stored procedures it is passed as such and they are working fine. To day i just decided to create a new overload in my DAL and here i am facing this weird problem.

Comment: Can it be due to SqlClient corruption? or temp file issues ?